# 301 redirect some products, categories and cms pages from old domain to new domain

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, url, redirect, .htaccess

I have this situation:

> - Site1.com (3 store views: *en*, *it* and *de*)
> - Site2.com (1 store view)

I need to redirect everything from **`site1.com`** (only **`en`** **store view** which is default) to **`site2.com`**. The other **2 store views** that should remain on **`site1.com`** are separated like this:

> - Site1.com/it
> - Site1.com/de

Any help would be welcomed, thanks!

Is possible using **Magento URL Management to redirect links to external site**? All I could find was how to redirect inside the same domain name.

I think I found it myself how to do it with **`.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^it
RewriteCond $1 !^de
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a .htaccess rewrite would do the trick

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(it|de)/
RewriteRule ^/(.*).html$ http://www.site2.com/$1.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

This will redirect all the urls from site1.com that don't start with `/it/` or `/de/` to site site2.com

Comment: Thanks, but the /en store view is default and accessible without the store code. What i need is somehow to redirect everything except all site1.com/it and site1.com/de

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an ignore condition for the it and de storecode

Comment: Thanks. Is your sollution better then what i found? Just want to be sure. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah I see you found the same solution. well technically they do the same. Using mine you always keep one condition no matter how many codes you add. But both will work fine :)